# How can I give precise instructions to qmake to build a lib file using MSVC lib.exe, e.g. "lib.exe /DEF:mylib.def /OUT:mylib.lib

Tags: visual-c++, qmake, lib

I want to know how to give qmake precise platform-specific instructions to build a library file using MSVC tools.

I want to be able to build a .lib from a downloaded third-party library (specifically SQLite 3, direct download includes .dll and .def files).  [I'm NOT interested in building from SQLite C source directly.]  I know I can build a .lib for MSVC platform basically by "lib.exe /def:sqlite3.def /out:sqlite3.lib" ... but I would like to know how to incorporate this step in the automated (qmake-based) build process rather than doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

So you're not going to build anything from sources, but rather to add some custom intermediate target to an existing project. It could be done like this:

```
# paths to our files
SQLITE3LIB = sqlite3.lib
SQLITE3DLL = sqlite3.dll

# an extra target for make
lsql.target = $$SQLITE3LIB
lsql.depends = $$SQLITE3DLL
lsql.commands = $$QMAKE_LIB /out:$$SQLITE3LIB $$SQLITE3DLL
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += lsql

# add a (makefile-)dependency for our main target
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$SQLITE3LIB
```